# How to echo all the files inside the folder using bat file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a bat file `'abc.bat'.` When I will double click it,I want to see all the `files` being listed using `echo` that were inside those folders. I looked into the SO previous answers and tried to use them but it didn't worked.

My path is:

```
\\intranet.com\pit\tail\ger\ger\FTP\SMS\2022-05-31
```

The folder `2022-05-31` has files inside it.I want those list of files outputted when bat file
gets executed.

I tried some solutions:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.*) do echo %%i
```

Another solution was:

```
for /r %%i in (\\intranet.com\pit\tail\ger\ger\FTP\SMS\2022-05-31) do echo %%i
```

But instead of showing files of `\\intranet.com\pit\tail\ger\ger\FTP\SMS\2022-05-31` it showed all the files in `C:/` drive location

Comment: 1. ```@PushD "\\intranet.com\pit\tail\ger\ger\FTP\SMS\2022-05-31" 2>NUL || Exit /B```, 2. ```@Dir /B /A:-D```, 3. ```@Pause```.

Comment: please post the ans separately so i can tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way to do this is to define the network target location as a temporary mapping first, then perform your directory listing.

Example:

```bash
@PushD "\\intranet.com\pit\tail\ger\ger\FTP\SMS\2022-05-31" 2>NUL || Exit /B
@Dir /B /A:-D
@Pause
```

To look up each command, and how it works, please open a Command Prompt window, and type each of the following:

```bash
pushd /?
```

```bash
exit /?
```

```bash
dir /?
```

```bash
pause /?
```

As a side note, you could do it as a one liner:

```bash
@PushD "\\intranet.com\pit\tail\ger\ger\FTP\SMS\2022-05-31" 2>NUL && (Dir /B /A:-D & Pause) || Exit /B
```